# function to read an input from a buffer that contains a file

Tags: c

I have this function that communicates with a tcp server

```c
char write_buffer[128];
char read_buffer[128];
char hint_status[4];
char Fsize[10];
FILE *score;
char lnk[1024];
int Fsize_max = 1024*1024*1024;

int hint(){
    if (connect(tcpfd, tcpres->ai_addr, tcpres->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
        return 0;
    }
    sprintf(write_buffer,"GHL %s\n",PLID);
    n=write(tcpfd, write_buffer,strlen(write_buffer));
    n=read(tcpfd, read_buffer, 128);
    sscanf(read_buffer, "%s %s %s %s %s\n", message_type, hint_status, Fname, Fsize, lnk);
    if(strcmp(hint_status, "NOK") == 0){
        return 0;
    };

    if (atoi(Fsize) > Fsize_max){
        printf("size_overflow\n");
        return 0;
    }

    score = fopen(Fname, "w+");
    fwrite(lnk, 1, sizeof(lnk), score);
    fclose(score);
    return 0;
}
```

That sends  information to the server and in return is supposed to receive "RHL status [Fname Fsize Fdata]" in what status is to check if the it return a file or not,  and

- the filename `Fname` (it comes in .PNG or .JPG)
- the file size `Fsize`, in bytes;
- the contents of the selected file (`Fdata`).

I am supposed to receive `RHL OK something.PGN 99123(for example) data` and I am receiving `RHL OK 5 12` or some times segmentation fault.

I know I am doing something wrong but I am not surely what.

Does any body have a clue on what is wrong with it?

Comment: You should check how many bytes were written and received and send/receive remaining data if not all bytes were transferred at once.

Comment: What exactly is the question? Does the code compile? If it complies, does it produce any warnings or errors? What was the expected output and what output did you actually observe?

Comment: You should also check how many parameters were converted with `sscanf` and how long the last string `lnk` is. You just write the complete buffer `lnk` into your output file no matter how long the string it.

Comment: ```read, write, fwrite, sscanf, and fclose``` all return something. Check for them.

Comment: `sscanf` expects a string as first parameter. If the other end of your connection also uses `strlen(buf)` to send data to you, the nul-terminator will not be included and as a result, `read` will not create a valid string. (As `readbuf` for some reason is a global variable, it will contain zeros when the function is called for the first time, but not for any later calls.) You must add nul-terminator yourself. Maybe something lile `read_buffer[n]=0;`

Answer (score 0):

> Does any body have a clue on what is wrong with it?

Yes

**Missing null character**

`n=write(tcpfd, write_buffer,strlen(write_buffer));` does not write a *string* as no *null character* is sent.

Consider

```
n=write(tcpfd, write_buffer,strlen(write_buffer) + 1);
```

`sscanf(read_buffer...` expects a *string*, yet `read_buffer[]` is not certainly null character terminated.

Use return value `n` to examine `read_buffer[]` and determine and append a `'\0'` as needed.

**Candidate problem: no width**

Without widths, code risks buffer overflow and undefined behavior (UB).

`char Fsize[10];` cannot save as text, `Fsize_max`, or "1073741824", which needs size 11.

Use widths to prevent buffer overflow.

**Use better scan checking**

```
// sscanf(read_buffer, "%s %s %s %s %s\n", 
//     message_type, hint_status, Fname, Fsize, lnk);

char message_type[10];  // True size is unknown as not posted by OP.
char Fname[100];        // True size is unknown as not posted by OP.
int n = 0;
sscanf(read_buffer, "%9s %3s %99s %9s %1023s %n", 
    message_type, hint_status, Fname, Fsize, lnk, &n);
if (n == 0 || read_buffer[n]) {
  TBD_CODE_Handle_Error():
}
```

---

For error checking, do not assume text in `int` range.

```
// if (atoi(Fsize) > Fsize_max){
if (atoll(Fsize) > Fsize_max){
```